# Question about arxiv

Tags: arxiv

Hello, 
I have the following question about arxiv.org: is it possible to cross list a mathematical
paper (already posted) to one of the physics archives (hep-th for example).
It definitely used to be possible, but the current system doesn't seem to allow that (at least
not in the obvious way).

Comment: http://arxiv.org/help/cross

Answer (score 2):

http://arxiv.org/help/cross as noted above.